# correção de erros

Tags: html, json

Alguem me consegue ajudar a resolver esses 3 erros? eu já tive a procura da solução na net mas dizem me para fazer assim e eu nao sei porque esta a dar erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: posta o codigo num codepen ou mesmo aqui , pelo print é complicado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na linha 9 falta fechar aspas

> onchange="change_myselect(this.value)>

```
onchange="change_myselect(this.value)">
```

Comment: Wow... ok obrigado :)

Comment: @DavidMv marque a resposta do Ronaldo como solução se resolveu seu problema.

Comment: De nada. Isso resolveu o problema? Se sim, marque como resposta correta para fechar a pergunta. :)

Comment: eu esqueço sempre sorry